# Swagger Schema - Pattern and length not applied to string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, yaml, pattern-matching

This is related to this question: [Swagger Schema - Pattern not applied to string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184411/swagger-schema-pattern-not-applied-to-string-array) which has received an answer that checks an array of fields (like key-values) instead of a list of single strings. I need the body of the request to look like this:

```
{
    "languages": [
        "english"
    ]
}
```

not like this (as the answer I was mentioning refers to):

```
{
  "languages": [
    {
      "language": "english"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the swagger piece I am using right now:

```
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: 'object'
              additionalProperties: false
              properties:
                languages:
                  type: 'array'
                  items:
                    type: 'string'
                    pattern: "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,50}$"
                    maxLength: 50
                    example: 'english'
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Would you please share that?

Comment: I have tried 
```
 requestBody:
        description: ''
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: 'object'
              properties:
                languages:
                  type: 'array'
                  items:
                    type: 'string'
                    pattern: "^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,50}$"
                    maxLength: 50
                    example: 'english'
```

Comment: please add your current swagger in the question. Not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
Languages:
  type: object
  properties:
    languages:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

And you can refer this `Language` Schema.

Comment: ```
requestBody:
        description: ''
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              languages:
                type: object
                properties:
                  language:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/language'
```
this is not valid swagger

Comment: I have not created complete swagger for you. I just mentioned how to create Array in your requested format. This is part of swagger. That's why I asked to share your current swagger.